# I am unable to fetch the subscription ID from my Google Play Store Console Giving Error Item Not Found

Tags: javascript, android, in-app-purchase, subscription

I received a message when i going to purchase my subscription from my android app.  Check where i am going to mistake.

i define this code sperate java file config.java

```
public static final String SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "1monthsubscription";
public static final String MERCHANT_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ; // PUT YOUR MERCHANT KEY HERE;
public static final long   SUBSCRIPTION_DURATION = 30; // PUT SUBSCRIPTION DURATION DAYS HERE;
```

and that is my LoadActivity.java

```
package com.enjoykids.vod.ui.activities;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService;
import com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.BillingProcessor;
import com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.Constants;
import com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.TransactionDetails;
import com.greenfrvr.rubberloader.RubberLoaderView;
import com.enjoykids.vod.Provider.PrefManager;
import com.enjoykids.vod.R;
import com.enjoykids.vod.api.apiClient;
import com.enjoykids.vod.api.apiRest;
import com.enjoykids.vod.config.Global;
import com.enjoykids.vod.entity.ApiResponse;
import com.enjoykids.vod.entity.Channel;
import com.enjoykids.vod.entity.Poster;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class LoadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private PrefManager prf;
IInAppBillingService mService;
private BillingProcessor bp;
private boolean readyToPurchase = false;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "iabv3";
private static final String MERCHANT_ID=null;

private  Integer id;
private String type;

ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mService = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name,
                                   IBinder service) {
        mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    int time = 3000;
    Uri data = this.getIntent().getData();
    if (data==null){
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras() ;
        if (bundle!=null) {
            this.id = bundle.getInt("id");
            this.type = bundle.getString("type");
            time = 2000;
        }
    }else{
        if (data.getPath().contains("/c/share/")){
            this.id=Integer.parseInt(data.getPath().replace("/c/share/","").replace(".html",""));
            this.type = "channel";
            time = 2000;
        }else{
            this.id=Integer.parseInt(data.getPath().replace("/share/","").replace(".html",""));
            this.type = "poster";
            time = 2000;
        }
    }



    prf= new PrefManager(getApplicationContext());
    initBuy();
    ( (RubberLoaderView) findViewById(R.id.loader1)).startLoading();
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // If you want to modify a view in your Activity
            LoadActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    checkAccount();

                }
            });
        }
    }, time);

    prf.setString("ADMIN_REWARDED_ADMOB_ID","");

    prf.setString("ADMIN_INTERSTITIAL_ADMOB_ID","");
    prf.setString("ADMIN_INTERSTITIAL_FACEBOOK_ID","");
    prf.setString("ADMIN_INTERSTITIAL_TYPE","FALSE");
    prf.setInt("ADMIN_INTERSTITIAL_CLICKS",3);

    prf.setString("ADMIN_BANNER_ADMOB_ID","");
    prf.setString("ADMIN_BANNER_FACEBOOK_ID","");
    prf.setString("ADMIN_BANNER_TYPE","FALSE");

    prf.setString("ADMIN_NATIVE_FACEBOOK_ID","");
    prf.setString("ADMIN_NATIVE_ADMOB_ID","");
    prf.setString("ADMIN_NATIVE_LINES","6");
    prf.setString("ADMIN_NATIVE_TYPE","FALSE");
}


private void checkAccount() {

    Integer version = -1;
    try {
        PackageInfo pInfo = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        version = pInfo.versionCode;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (version!=-1){
        Integer id_user = 0;

        if (prf.getString("LOGGED").toString().equals("TRUE")) {
            id_user = Integer.parseInt(prf.getString("ID_USER"));
        }
        Retrofit retrofit = apiClient.getClient();
        apiRest service = retrofit.create(apiRest.class);
        Call<ApiResponse> call = service.check(version,id_user);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ApiResponse> call, Response<ApiResponse> response) {
                updateTextViews();
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getValues().size(); i++) {
                        if ( response.body().getValues().get(i).getName().equals("ADMIN_REWARDED_ADMOB_ID") ){
                            if (response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue()!=null)
                                prf.setString("ADMIN_REWARDED_ADMOB_ID",response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue());
                        }
                        if ( response.body().getValues().get(i).getName().equals("ADMIN_INTERSTITIAL_ADMOB_ID") ){
                            if (response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue()!=null)
                                prf.setString("ADMIN_INTERSTITIAL_ADMOB_ID",response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue());
                        }
                        if ( response.body().getValues().get(i).getName().equals("ADMIN_INTERSTITIAL_FACEBOOK_ID") ){
                            if (response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue()!=null)
                                prf.setString("ADMIN_INTERSTITIAL_FACEBOOK_ID",response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue());
                        }
                        if ( response.body().getValues().get(i).getName().equals("ADMIN_INTERSTITIAL_TYPE") ){
                            if (response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue()!=null)
                                prf.setString("ADMIN_INTERSTITIAL_TYPE",response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue());
                        }
                        if ( response.body().getValues().get(i).getName().equals("ADMIN_INTERSTITIAL_CLICKS") ){
                            if (response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue()!=null)
                                prf.setInt("ADMIN_INTERSTITIAL_CLICKS",Integer.parseInt(response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue()));
                        }
                        if ( response.body().getValues().get(i).getName().equals("ADMIN_BANNER_ADMOB_ID") ){
                            if (response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue()!=null)
                                prf.setString("ADMIN_BANNER_ADMOB_ID",response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue());
                        }
                        if ( response.body().getValues().get(i).getName().equals("ADMIN_BANNER_FACEBOOK_ID") ){
                            if (response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue()!=null)
                                prf.setString("ADMIN_BANNER_FACEBOOK_ID",response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue());
                        }
                        if ( response.body().getValues().get(i).getName().equals("ADMIN_BANNER_TYPE") ){
                            if (response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue()!=null)
                                prf.setString("ADMIN_BANNER_TYPE",response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue());
                        }
                        if ( response.body().getValues().get(i).getName().equals("ADMIN_NATIVE_FACEBOOK_ID") ){
                            if (response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue()!=null)
                                prf.setString("ADMIN_NATIVE_FACEBOOK_ID",response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue());
                        }
                        if ( response.body().getValues().get(i).getName().equals("ADMIN_NATIVE_ADMOB_ID") ){
                            if (response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue()!=null)
                                prf.setString("ADMIN_NATIVE_ADMOB_ID",response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue());
                        }
                        if ( response.body().getValues().get(i).getName().equals("ADMIN_NATIVE_LINES") ){
                            if (response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue()!=null)
                                prf.setString("ADMIN_NATIVE_LINES",response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue());
                        }
                        if ( response.body().getValues().get(i).getName().equals("ADMIN_NATIVE_TYPE") ){
                            if (response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue()!=null)
                                prf.setString("ADMIN_NATIVE_TYPE",response.body().getValues().get(i).getValue());
                        }
                    }
                    if (response.body().getValues().get(1).getValue().equals("403")){
                        prf.remove("ID_USER");
                        prf.remove("SALT_USER");
                        prf.remove("TOKEN_USER");
                        prf.remove("NAME_USER");
                        prf.remove("TYPE_USER");
                        prf.remove("USERN_USER");
                        prf.remove("IMAGE_USER");
                        prf.remove("LOGGED");
                        Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.account_disabled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                    }
                    if (id!=null && type !=null){
                        if (type.equals("poster"))
                            getPoster();
                        if (type.equals("channel"))
                            getChannel();
                    }else{
                        if (response.body().getCode().equals(200)) {
                            if (!prf.getString("first").equals("true")){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoadActivity.this,IntroActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
                                finish();
                                prf.setString("first","true");
                            }else{
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoadActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }else if (response.body().getCode().equals(202)) {
                            String title_update=response.body().getValues().get(0).getValue();
                            String featurs_update=response.body().getMessage();
                            View v = (View)  getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.update_message,null);
                            TextView update_text_view_title=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.update_text_view_title);
                            TextView update_text_view_updates=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.update_text_view_updates);
                            update_text_view_title.setText(title_update);
                            update_text_view_updates.setText(featurs_update);
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder;
                            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoadActivity.this);
                            builder.setTitle("New Update")
                                    //.setMessage(response.body().getValue())
                                    .setView(v)
                                    .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.update_now), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            final String appPackageName=getApplication().getPackageName();
                                            try {
                                                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                                            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                                                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                                            }
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.skip), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            if (!prf.getString("first").equals("true")){
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoadActivity.this,IntroActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
                                                finish();
                                                prf.setString("first","true");
                                            }else{
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoadActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
                                                finish();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .setCancelable(false)
                                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_update)
                                    .show();
                        } else {
                            if (!prf.getString("first").equals("true")){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoadActivity.this,IntroActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
                                finish();
                                prf.setString("first","true");
                            }else{
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoadActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else {

                    if (id!=null && type !=null){
                        if (type.equals("poster"))
                            getPoster();
                        if (type.equals("channel"))
                            getChannel();
                    }else{
                        if (!prf.getString("first").equals("true")){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoadActivity.this,IntroActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
                            finish();
                            prf.setString("first","true");
                        }else{
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoadActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                updateTextViews();

                if (id!=null && type !=null){
                    if (type.equals("poster"))
                        getPoster();
                    if (type.equals("channel"))
                        getChannel();
                }else{
                    if (!prf.getString("first").equals("true")){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoadActivity.this,IntroActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
                        finish();
                        prf.setString("first","true");
                    }else{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoadActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }else{
        updateTextViews();

        if (id!=null && type !=null){
            if (type.equals("poster"))
                getPoster();
            if (type.equals("channel"))
                getChannel();
        }else{
            if (!prf.getString("first").equals("true")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoadActivity.this,IntroActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
                finish();
                prf.setString("first","true");
            }else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoadActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

}
private void initBuy() {
    Intent serviceIntent =
            new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
    bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


    if(!BillingProcessor.isIabServiceAvailable(this)) {
        //  showToast("In-app billing service is unavailable, please upgrade Android Market/Play to version >= 3.9.16");
    }

    bp = new BillingProcessor(this, Global.MERCHANT_KEY, MERCHANT_ID, new BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details) {
            updateTextViews();
        }
        @Override
        public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onBillingInitialized() {
            readyToPurchase = true;
            updateTextViews();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
            for(String sku : bp.listOwnedProducts())
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Owned Managed Product: " + sku);
            for(String sku : bp.listOwnedSubscriptions())
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Owned Subscription: " + sku);
            updateTextViews();
        }
    });
    bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unbindService(mServiceConn);
}

private void updateTextViews() {
    PrefManager prf= new PrefManager(getApplicationContext());
    bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();
    if(isSubscribe(Global.SUBSCRIPTION_ID)){
        prf.setString("SUBSCRIBED","TRUE");
    }
    else{
        prf.setString("SUBSCRIBED","FALSE");
    }
}
public Boolean isSubscribe(String SUBSCRIPTION_ID_CHECK){

    if (!bp.isSubscribed(Global.SUBSCRIPTION_ID))
        return false;


    Bundle b =  getPurchases();
    if (b==null)
        return  false;
    if( b.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE") == 0){
        ArrayList<String> ownedSkus =
                b.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
        ArrayList<String>  purchaseDataList =
                b.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
        ArrayList<String>  signatureList =
                b.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST");
        String continuationToken =
                b.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");


        if(purchaseDataList == null){
            return  false;

        }
        if(purchaseDataList.size()==0){
            return  false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
            String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
            String signature = signatureList.get(i);
            String sku_1 = ownedSkus.get(i);
            //Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

            try {
                JSONObject rowOne = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                String  productId =  rowOne.getString("productId") ;

                if (productId.equals(SUBSCRIPTION_ID_CHECK)){

                    Boolean  autoRenewing =  rowOne.getBoolean("autoRenewing");
                    if (autoRenewing){
                        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
                        Long  purchaseTime =  rowOne.getLong("purchaseTime")/1000;
                        return  true;
                    }else{
                        // Toast.makeText(this, "is not autoRenewing ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
                        Long  purchaseTime =  rowOne.getLong("purchaseTime")/1000;
                        if (tsLong > (purchaseTime + (Global.SUBSCRIPTION_DURATION*86400)) ){
                            //   Toast.makeText(this, "is Expired ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return  false;
                        }else{
                            return  true;
                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }else{
        return false;
    }

    return  false;
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public Bundle getPurchases(){
    if (!bp.isInitialized()) {
        return null;
    }
    try{

        return  mService.getPurchases(Constants.GOOGLE_API_VERSION, getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Constants.PRODUCT_TYPE_SUBSCRIPTION, null);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // Toast.makeText(this, "ex", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public void getPoster(){

    Retrofit retrofit = apiClient.getClient();
    apiRest service = retrofit.create(apiRest.class);
    Call<Poster> call = service.getPosterById(id);
    call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<Poster>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Poster> call, Response<Poster> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (response.body().getType().equals("serie")) {
                    Intent in = new Intent(LoadActivity.this,SerieActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra("poster", response.body());
                    in.putExtra("from", "true");
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();
                }if (response.body().getType().equals("movie")){
                    Intent in = new Intent(LoadActivity.this,MovieActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra("poster", response.body());
                    in.putExtra("from", "true");
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Poster> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
public void getChannel(){

    Retrofit retrofit = apiClient.getClient();
    apiRest service = retrofit.create(apiRest.class);
    Call<Channel> call = service.geChannelById(id);
    call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<Channel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Channel> call, Response<Channel> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                Intent in = new Intent(LoadActivity.this,ChannelActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("channel", response.body());
                in.putExtra("from", "true");
                startActivity(in);
                finish();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Channel> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Now, when i add the subscription ID and Merchat ID and upload my app on google app console. But after publish when i click on subscription which includes remove ads, can download product, Play premium content its show error item not found. I also add this in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

but its not working can anyone help me why this error coming and why its not fetching my subscription_ID which i created in my Google Play console.